# Crystal Report - Cannot login into DB c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, crystal-reports

I'm using crystal report on WinFrom( the report contains only 1 table).

I have two machines, on the first one everything works fine(Windows 10).
but on the second( Windows 7) I cannot seem to log in to the DB.

I have copied the whole project, as is, from the working machine to the one with the problem, but the problem persists.
no error message, no exception, just some generic "Login Failed, Please try again"

As far as I have researched the only difference between the machine is the DB (Microsoft SQL server) itself, beside the DB name it seems that in the working machine, the property `IntegratedSecurity` is not required (working with or without this property). But on the machine with the problem, this property seems to be required, but even when I set `IntegratedSecurity = true` the problem remains.

I looked [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1225872/Crystal-reports-database-logon-failed-error) and [here](https://www.blakepell.com/2012-05-22-crystal-reports-extension-methods) for refrences

```
public static void printReport(string id)
{           
   using (var frmPrint = new FrmPrint(id))
   {
        SetTableConnectionInfo(frmPrint);

        frmPrint.palletLablePaving.SetParameterValue(0, id);
#if DEBUG
        frmPrint.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = frmPrint.palletLablePaving;
        frmPrint.ShowDialog();
#else
        frmPrint.palletLablePaving.PrintToPrinter(nCopies: 1, collated: false, startPageN: 0, endPageN: 0);
#endif
     }
  }


private static void SetTableConnectionInfo(FrmPrint frmPrint)
{

     foreach (Table table in frmPrint.palletLablePaving.Database.Tables)
     {
         // Get the ConnectionInfo Object.
            var logOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
            var connectionInfo = logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo;

              // Set the Connection parameters.
              connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "APP5D";
              connectionInfo.ServerName = @".\YP_LINE5_DRY";
              connectionInfo.UserID = "admin";
              connectionInfo.Password = "myPssword";
              connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = true; // not affecting the result
              table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);
       }

}
```

**P.S**
I cannot change anything in the report or in the DB properties

**Edit**
the working machine using SQL server version 11(2012) and the machine with the problem using version 12(2014)

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: @reckface no error message, no exception, just some generic "Login Failed, Please try again"

Comment: connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = true uses windows credentials so you cannot have a username and password.  For windows credentials to work the following must occur 1) Database is configured to Windows credentials 2) There is same group account on local PC and Server (or network uses Group Policies) 3)  The user is in the Group on Local and Remote PC.  I would recommend start with SQL Server management Studio and see if you can access database.  The login windows server name and instance should be same as application.  The login windows should show Windows Credentials.

Comment: @styx ok, what's the version of SQL native client on each machine? jdweng is right, don't use both IntegratedSecurity and credentials, in Crystal, that doesn't work, although that's not your immediate problem

Comment: @reckface it appears on the main thread.

Comment: @styx SQL native client, not SQL server.

Comment: @jdweng thanks its a combination of (1) and (3)

Comment: If the account is setup correctly then you should be able to use SQL Server Management Studio to access database from local/remote PC which is the first thing I would try.  If this works then there is no reason your code shouldn't work provided you remove the user name and password from connection string and the Server_Name\Instance (.\YP_LINE5_DRY) matches the login window of SSMS.